# windows 7 failed to repair

Tags: windows, windows-7, repair

I need to do a repair in a Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit installation.
I disabled antivirus.
Inserted installation CD
  - Pressed install
  - Selected "Go online to get the latest updates for installation"
  - I clicked "Upgrade"
Process started but failed with message:

```
Setup can't continue. Restart computer and restart setup. When prompt try selecting getting latest installation updates
```

I restarted computer and setup but same error. Has anyone encountered this?
How can I find the cause of this failure?

PS
I do not have any restore point in the PC to do system restore

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem with a Win 7 Ultimate 32-Bit installation. Since a dozend repair attempts were failing i decided to do a re-installation but it ends up with such a error on missing a driver...

i did first a diskdump to save all data to a secure place, with a ubuntu live-cd. Do you have a backup of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a clean boot, then install.

Open MSCONFIG, go to the startup tab and uncheck everything, then go to the Services tab and tick "Hide all Microsoft services", then uncheck all Non Microsoft services, restart and try to repair.

http://netsquirrel.com/msconfig/msconfig_win7.html

Once the repair install is complete, re-enable what you disabled.

Comment: @Moab:What do you mean "Perform a clean boot, then install"?Just boot the machine and do the procedure you describe?

Comment: No, perform the clean boot procedure first, when you reboot is will be in a "clean" state, no software or services loaded that could interfere with the repair.

Comment: ok.I did all these.Windows passes the "Copying installation files to your computer" but fails on the next step "Selecting programs etc" with same message.How can I know what is the error?

Comment: Sometimes setup will make a log, search your hard drive for  setupact.log and setuperr.log, see what is in the log files, open with notepad.

Comment: setuperr.log mentions "Error: Failed to find driver file path" numerous times and "STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND". I do not understand what this means

Comment: Run the W7 Upgrade advisor, see if it flags anything in its report...http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15